# How can I increment a variable in 'git submodule foreach'?

Tags: bash, git

I can create a counter variable with `export CNT=1`. Furthermore I can increment it by defining a function like

```
$ function foo()
> {
>    export  CNT=$(($CNT+1))
>    echo $CNT
> }
$ export -f foo
$ foo
2
```

However, when I try to adapt this into the `git submodule foreach`  command (`git submodule foreach foo`), my counter variable remains '1'.

I guess this has to do with the visibility of the variable and the creation of new shell instances, but I couldn't figure out how exactly it works in the combination with `git submodule foreach`.

I appreciate any answer, that gives me a good explanation.

BTW: Of course, I have several submodules.

Comment: I'm not sure about your submodule stuff, but you should be running export  CNT=$(($CNT+1)) at each turn to increment it.

Comment: The obvious (even though not very clean) solution is to create a temporary file somewhere in /tmp/ and store the target value there.

Comment: I'd disagree with that. Also it's unclear if he's calling foo again or not. 
$ foo
1
$ foo
2
$ foo
3
$ foo
4
$ foo
5
$ echo $CNT
5
$ echo $CNT
5
$ echo $CNT
5
$ foo
6
$ echo $CNT
6

Comment: I run only `git submodules foreach foo` and I would expect that foo is called once for every submodule, but for every submodule it stays '1', as I wrote

Comment: @hidefromkgb This would be a workaround but would only use it when there is no other solution.

Comment: The function must be run inside a subshell, in which case the modification of the variable in the context of the subshell isn't propagated to the calling shell : https://ideone.com/uc1s72

Comment: What happens if you try `git submodules foreach 'echo $((++i))'` ? If you have the same problem, it means `git` itself creates subshells in which to run the command you provide it. That would mean you have to use something else than a variable, as subshells are made to not be able to modify their parent shell's environment. If you don't reproduce the problem on the other hand, it means you are using a subshell somewhere which you might be able to get rid of

Comment: @Aaron This also delivers only '1's. True, that this excluds that my function is used wrongly. So there is probably no way in using a variable?

Comment: Right, unless you want to only use `git` to list the submodules and then handle the command execution yourself, then you could do whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, `git submodule foreach` runs each command in its own separate shell instance.  This means any variable or environment-variable settings are discarded as soon as the sub-command has finished operating on any one particular submodule.

Originally, `git submodule` was all one big shell script.  Some of this script still remains [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-submodule.sh).  The `cmd_foreach` function in this script invokes [`builtin/submodule--helper.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/submodule--helper.c), which runs the specified command via function [`runcommand_in_submodule_cb`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7034cd094bda4edbcdff7fad1a28fcaaf9b9a040/builtin/submodule--helper.c#L455).

To achieve what you want—a "global"-ish counter across all submodules (perhaps recursively so)—you'll need to copy the current count to/from something that survives each new shell instance startup.  You could use a fixed file name, such as `/tmp/counter`, to hold your variable, though of course this means you cannot run separate `git submodule foreach`-es in parallel in different superprojects.  Or, you could use a per-repository file, perhaps by using the setting in `$toplevel` as provided by the submodule helper (consider turning `$toplevel` into a hash ID and using `/tmp/counter.$hash` or similar, or—if it's OK for your own situation—a fixed file name within `$toplevel`, which is your current working directory when you start the whole thing off).

You can export the current value of some variable(s) using, e.g.:

```
echo VAR=$VAR > $file
```

and then simply source (`.`) the file to recover the value:

```
. $file
```

though be aware that this opens potential security issues (if someone else can overwrite `$file` while your scripts runs).

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks for the provided links. This is actually an answer. Another confirmation that git's submodules are not the best invention that was ever made.